Fantasy book about teenagers transported into a magical world, where they turn into creatures from that world
I read a book about 10-15 years ago about a group of teenagers that randomly are transported to a magical world. They slowly turn into creatures of that world.
The main protagonist is a boy that turns into a demon or something? And he meets another demon from that world called Rafael I believe. One of the girls turns into a werewolf, and another girl which I think is called Rachel is the only one without any magical powers. (But she also isn't affected by any magic spells due to that, including the one that lets them all understand the language of that world.)
At the end there is some sort of big war between the good and evil powers.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33940395-the-key-to-the-demon-s-gate has three teenagers gaining different powers from the demon that they switched places with but no Rafael or Rachel and I haven't found any mention of werewolves or someone getting immunity to magic.

Thanks! Still seems like a cool book!
